# How to set Block local variables by code?

Tags: programming, scoping, code-request

I need to create a user-defined `Block` function where the `Block` variables' values are defined by code.  For example, imagine I have:

```
SetAttributes[myBlock1,HoldAll]
myBlock1[args_]:=Block[{a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4},args]
myBlock1[{a,b,c,d}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

Now, what I need is something like:

```
SetAttributes[myBlock2,HoldAll]
varList={"a","b","c","d"};

myBlock2[args_]:=Module[{varArgs},
    varArgs=MapIndexed[ToString@Row[{#1,"=",#2[[1]]}]&,varList];
    ToExpression@ToString@Row[{"Block[",varArgs,",",ToString@args,"]"}]
]

myBlock2[{a,b,c,d}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

The above function works, but it's very clumsy (using `ToExpression`) and error-susceptible.  I tried something like:

```
SetAttributes[myBlock3,HoldAll]
varList={"a","b","c","d"};

myBlock3[args_]:=ReleaseHold[Hold@Block[varDef,args]/.varDef:>MapIndexed[(Evaluate@Symbol[#1]=#2[[1]])&,varList]]
myBlock3[{a,b,c,d}]
```

But without success in the "variables injection."  One important point is that `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` should not escape from the block scope.  How can I do that?

Comment: The third argument of `ToExpression` is your saviour

Comment: But the idea is to get rid of `ToExpression`. :)

Comment: And what's the practical objective of that idea?

Comment: Idea to get rid of `ToExpression`? A simple variation like `myBlock2[r={1,2,3};r[[b]]]` do not work with this solution, but is ok with the first one.

Comment: I might understand you want to get rid of the clumsiness of writing code in strings, but you need `ToExpression` at least for the variables, the moment you decide to store your variables as strings.

Comment: Why not Evaluate@Symbol["x"]? I just don't know how to insert it on Block as `Block[{Evaluate@Symbol["x"]=1},args]`

Comment: If you evaluate `Symbol["x"]` and `x` has a value, it will evaluate to the value and not `x`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7549/discussion-between-murta-and-rojo)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two standard methods are SlotSequence, and the "injector pattern."
Related question on StackOverflow:  [How to Block Symbols without evaluating them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234701/618728)

#### SlotSequence

```
ClearAll[myBlock]

SetAttributes[myBlock, HoldAll]

varList = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

myBlock[args_] :=
 Function[Null, Block[{##}, args], HoldAll] @@
  (MapIndexed[Set, Join @@ MakeExpression@varList] /. {x_} :> x)

myBlock[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

#### Injector pattern

```
ClearAll[myBlock]

SetAttributes[myBlock, HoldAll]

varList = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

myBlock[args_] :=
 (MapIndexed[Set, Join @@ MakeExpression@varList] /. {x_} :> x) /.
   _[sets__] :> Block[{sets}, args]

myBlock[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Comment: Nicer than what I drafted in chat, go get the 50k

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You and yours Mathemagics!.. Now I need to study it. Tks! +1

Answer (score 7):

Just an alternative, the abuse of `Hold` pattern

```
varList = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

    SetAttributes[myBlock, HoldFirst];

myBlock[args_]:=
   Hold[Block][
      MakeExpression@varList~Hold[Set]~Range@Length@varList // Thread, 
      Hold[args]] // ReleaseHold
```

Comment: Why not `Range@Length@varList`? tks +1

Comment: Sure, I didn't know if that was the general intention. Editing

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add that I personally prefer to deal with lists of symbols rather than lists of strings that are implied to convert into symbols later in functions. That way I get errors from incorrectly formated strings early rather then getting them buried deeply in an application when something runs `Symbol[string]` or worse `ToExpression[string]` and expects a single symbol. Naturally you can't just have a list of symbols, since they might evaluate, but you can just pretend `HoldComplete` is `List` for a moment, and in fact most build-in functions (`Map`, `Sort`... the list goes on), don't actually require you to pass things with the `List` head. Anyway to cut a long rant short, here's a function to convert a list of strings to a `HoldComplete` filled with symbols:

```
stringsToSymbols[strings_] := 
 With[{ res =       
       strings/.a_String:>ToExpression[a,InputForm,Hold]//HoldComplete@@#/.Hold[a_]:>a& },
 res/;MatchQ[res,HoldComplete[___Symbol]]]

stringsToSymbols::wrdf="Input strings did not convert nicely to symbol list `1` ";
stringlistToSymHold[s_]:=Message[stringsToSymbols::wrdf,s]
```

So when needing something like your block function I'll just assume the format:

```
varList=HoldComplete[a,b,c,d]
```

Now the above works nicely with the methods presented by Mr. Wizard and Rojo, but I'll show another one just to add it, which is one I've used occasionally. What I do is build the expression-structure using `HoldComplete` and `Lists` instead of for instance `With` `Block` and similar. I then substitute out all the desired heads at once at the end:

```
 myBlock[args_] := 
   ReplacePart[
   List[MapIndexed[Set, varList] /. {x_} :> x, 
      args], {{0} -> Block, {1, 0} -> List}]
```

Here I'd note that I would typically take `varList` as an input adding `varList : HoldComplete[__Symbol]` to the function definition, just to avoid reliance on globals.

Comment: Hi @jVincent! The `HoldComplete` is a nice tip. About convert text into symbols, I don't like it too, but the  variables names came from the names of a SQL query columns, and they are text that I needed to convert into local variables. I have no other option. Tks for your answer!

Comment: @Murta That is why I showed a function to convert from strings to a held format. The point is that sometimes you *need* to have strings converted into symbols, but when you do, it's better to do so once early, rather than just assume everything will always work out nicely and do the conversion in the middle of other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility worth mentioning that I copy from Daniel Huber, found here
 http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Nov/msg00217.html.

It lacks the conversion from string to symbol, but it's already in other answers.

```
SetAttributes[CreateBlock, HoldAll];
CreateBlock[lvals_, rvals_, expr_] :=
Module[{v, myBlock, mySet, vals},
    v = Thread[mySet[lvals, rvals]];
    SetAttributes[myBlock, HoldAll];
    myBlock[vals, expr] /. vals -> v /. mySet -> Set /. myBlock -> Block
];
```