# Using a variable to tell Mathematica which existing variable to manipulate

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions, assignment

I have an estimation routine I have coded up, I want now to do some tests on it where I pick a particular parameter and run the estimation for differing values of that parameter. What I want is to be able to specify the parameter name I am interested in changing at the top of the file and from then on just run a loop substituting different values into the chosen parameter.

So for example I want something to the effect of

```
paramToVary = a;
paramValues = Range[0, 1, 1/20];

Do[MyEstimation[a, b], {paramToVary, paramValues}]
```

except this wont work as written, `paramToVary` takes the values of `paramValues` whereas I want these to be going into `a` instead. Any ideas on how to do this or alternative solutions?

Comment: Possibly related: "[Elegant manipulation of the variables list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/280)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Do` (and `Table`) has attribute `HoldAll`, `paramToVary` won't be evaluated at the right time. Use `Evaluate` on the iterator specification to force the replacement of `paramToVary` -> `a`.

```
ClearAll[a];
paramToVary = a;
paramValues = Range[0, 1, .2];

Table[a, Evaluate@{paramToVary, paramValues}]
```

> ```
> {0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Using `With` might do the trick too:

```
ClearAll[a];
With[{paramToVary = a, paramValues = Range[0, 1, .2]},
 Table[a, {paramToVary, paramValues}]
]
```

> ```
> {0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As described by István this is an issue of evaluation order.  There are several methods, `Evaluate` and `With` already illustrated.  I often use a `Function` for this purpose as it is concise:

```
paramToVary = a;
paramValues = Range[0, 1, 1/5];

Table[{a, b}, {#, paramValues}] & @ paramToVary
```

> ```
> {{0, b}, {1/5, b}, {2/5, b}, {3/5, b}, {4/5, b}, {1, b}}
> ```

There are potential complications with your approach that I wish to caution you about.  If the Symbol `a` has an assigned value this operation will fail because `paramToVary` will evaluate to that value rather than the Symbol `a`:

```
a = 999;
Table[{a, b}, {#, paramValues}] & @ paramToVary
```

> During evaluation of In[42]:= Table::itraw: Raw object 999 cannot be used as an iterator. >>

You can guard against this by keeping the Symbol in a `Hold` expression, and by using some method to insert the unevaluated Symbol into the `Table` (or `Do`) expression.  My favorite method for the latter is what I have come to call the ["injector pattern"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121).  Please also see [How to set Block local variables by code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/121) for a related question.

```
a = 999;

paramToVary = Hold[a]

paramToVary /. _[x_] :> Table[{a, b}, {x, paramValues}]
```

> ```
> {{0, b}, {1/5, b}, {2/5, b}, {3/5, b}, {4/5, b}, {1, b}}
> ```

Note that `a` had a value before `paramToVary` was defined without breaking the code.

Alternatively you can use [my `step` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447) which simplifies definition retrieval, and use `SetDelayed` rather than `Hold`:

```
a = 999;

paramToVary := a;

step[paramToVary] /. _[x_] :> Table[{a, b}, {x, paramValues}]
```

> ```
> {{0, b}, {1/5, b}, {2/5, b}, {3/5, b}, {4/5, b}, {1, b}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this extra detail, very helpful as I do have values stored in the parameters

Comment: @Matthew You're welcome.  Consider possibly Accepting this answer instead, if it is the solution you will use?