# Generate list of strings from a list of assigned variables

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, assignment, variable

How do I generate a list of strings from a list of assigned variables?

E.g. convert

```
var1 = 10;
var2 = 11;
var3 = 17;
var4 = 5;

compvar = {var1, var2, var3, var4}; (*all variables assigned*)
```

into

```
compvarstr = {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"};
```

Using `ToString` obviously converts the variables assignments into strings e.g.

```
compvarstr = ToString[#] & /@ compvar
```

gives,

> ```
>  {"10", "11", "17", "5"}
> ```

I'm after the unassigned variable names as strings e.g.

> ```
>  {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"};
> ```

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I had a bit of a look and nothing seemed to answer it.

Comment: you mean this? `compvarstr = ToString[#] & /@ compvar` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a01av.png)

Comment: @Nasser - please review my edit. I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: I see now after your edits. But what you are asking for can't be done as is. Once you make an assignment, compvar becomes `{10, 11, 17, 5}`, becuase M has evaluated all those variables to their values. Only way, is not to make the assignment to the valuates, but using replacement rule. I'll post an example

Comment: Related: [(10322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must introduce some form of holding in you definition of `compvar` as otherwise, assuming it is defined after `var1`, `var2`, etc., there is no information to retrieve:

```
var1 = 10;
var2 = 11;
var3 = 17;
var4 = 5;

compvar = {var1, var2, var3, var4};

Definition[compvar]
```

> ```
> compvar = {10, 11, 17, 5}
> ```

You could use `Hold` but then you would need to `ReleaseHold` (or similar) every time you used `compvar`.  Instead I suggest you use `SetDelayed` and then recover the definition using my `step` function from:

- [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447)

It returns an expression wrapped in [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html):

```
compvar := {var1, var2, var3, var4};

step[compvar] // InputForm
```

> ```
> HoldForm[{var1, var2, var3, var4}]
> ```

To convert to a list of strings:

```
Cases[step[compvar], s_Symbol :> SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ s, {2}]
```

> ```
> {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}
> ```

Or:

```
StringSplit[ToString @ step[compvar], ("{" | "," | " " | "}") ..]
```

> ```
> {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}
> ```

The first method will return Symbols (as strings) only while the second will convert other expressions as well.

---

Incidentally if you do not need to store your Symbols in a `List` you could use a more direct form:

```
compHeld = Hold[var1, var2, var3, var4];

List @@ SymbolName /@ Unevaluated /@ compHeld
```

> ```
> {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}
> ```

Comment: Nice explanation - Thanks.

Comment: @geordie You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a  way:

```
var1 = 10;
var2 = 11;
var3 = 17;
var4 = 5;
compvar := {var1, var2, var3, var4}
compvar; (*all variables assigned*)

ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, {HoldAll}];
f[x_, y__] := Flatten@{f[x], f[y]}
f[x_] := SymbolName@Unevaluated@x

OwnValues[compvar] /. {HoldPattern[y_] :> {x__}} :> f[x]

(*
 {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

one way is to make a replacement rule seperately and use that.

```
Clear[var1, var2, var3, var4];
vars = {var1, var2, var3, var4};
values = {var1 -> 10, var2 -> 11, var3 -> 17, var4 -> 5};
compvar = vars /. values
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
compvarstr = ToString[#] & /@ vars
FullForm[compvarstr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Otherwise, the way you had it:

```
 var1 = 10; var2 = 11; var3 = 17; var4 = 5;
 compvar = {var1, var2, var3, var4}; (*all variables assigned*)
```

Now the `var1` name itself is replaced by 10 right away by the evaluator. Hence `compvar` will always be `{10, 11, 17, 5}` and the name of the variables is not known inside `compvar` since their value is used.

Comment: This wont work for my case (setting up the rules each time will be a fiddle) but it has made me realise that going the other way is easy e.g. `compvar = ToExpression[compvarstr]`. Many thanks!

Comment: @geordie if that works for you then good. But I think writing `values = {var1 -> 10, var2 -> 11, var3 -> 17, var4 -> 5};` is not more a problem than writing `var1 = 10; var2 = 11; var3 = 17; var4 = 5;` and using replacement rule is more flexible in many other ways and for many other uses as well. But again, whatever works for you ;)

Comment: Agreed, however, in my full code "var1" through "var4" are nested lists and have names like "vh88exp1", "vh88sswl", "bpqm10", etc... So it is quite easy for me to write out their names as a list of strings. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Better late the never, right? I created this answer while thinking about one of recent questions that was a duplicate of this one.

I kind of like this way, it is compact and without `#&@` :)

```
ClearAll[VNL];
SetAttributes[VNL, HoldFirst];

VNL[list_] :=   Thread[
                       Hold[list] /. OwnValues[list]
                       ] /.    Hold[s_] :> (SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]])
```

Let's borrow belisarius' variables :)

```
var1 = 10;
var2 = 11;
var3 = 17;
var4 = 5;
compvar := {var1, var2, var3, var4}

VNL[ compvar ]
```

> ```
>   {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative, in which the values of the variables are temporarily cleared using `Block` and an [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19758/how-to-set-block-local-variables-by-code/19761#19761).

```
ClearAll[getSymbolNames];
SetAttributes[getSymbolNames, HoldAll];
getSymbolNames[list_Symbol] := 
 Hold[list] /. OwnValues[list] /. 
  Hold[{vars__Symbol}] :> Block[{vars}, SymbolName /@ {vars}]
```

With some planning one might initialized the list of variables before the values to `var1` etc. are assigned; otherwise, use `SetDelayed` as in the other answers.

```
Clear[var1, var2, var3, var4];
compvar0 = {var1, var2, var3, var4};

var1 = 10;
var2 = 11;
var3 = 17;
var4 = 5;

compvar := {var1, var2, var3, var4};

getSymbolNames[compvar0]
(*  {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}  *)

getSymbolNames[compvar]
(*  {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine your data in an associative way

```
data=<|
"var1"->10,
"var2"->11,
"var3"->17,
"var4"->5
|>
```

because it looks like you are simply looking for the `Keys` and the `Values` of your data

```
compvar = Values@data
compvarstr = Keys@data
```

> {10, 11, 17, 5}
>
> {"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"}