# Sorting a list of variables by the numerical value they represent

Tags: sorting

What would be the simplest method of sorting a list of variables according to the value they represent:

Let:

```
a = 5; b = 4; c = 3; d = 2; e = 1;
varList = {a, b, c, d, e};

Sort[varList]
```

Renders:

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

While my preferred output would be:

> `{e, d, c, b, a}`

I expect the answer will be embarrassingly simple.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I saw your comment yesterday. I was not able to elaborate more. But try to do this step by step and if something is not clear I can explain those parts, ok?

Comment: Ok, take a look at details for `Part`, 4th bullet point. It says that for `expr[[{a,b,c}]]` it will apply `Head` of expression for result. So I'm using something like `Defer[{1,2,3}][[{1}, {3,2,1}]]` to reorder things but preserve head `Defer`, it is done by `{1}`. Minimal example is: `Hold[{1,2,3}][[ {1}, 1]]`, take a look what it evaluates to.

Comment: Ahh! Crystal clear. Your minimal example did it. Thank you very much Kuba. Maybe you could squeeze in parts of this text in your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you use `:=` for `varList` definition. `a,b...` are lost. Here's more about that, in related Q&A: [Generate list of strings from a list of assigned variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69187/5478).

So:

```
a = 5; b = 4; c = 3; d = 2; e = 1;
varList := {a, b, c, d, e};

(Defer[varList] /. OwnValues[varList])[[{1}, Ordering[varList]]]
```

> ```
> {e, d, c, b, a}
> ```

Answer (score 14):

Here's another way you might approach this kind of thing -- instead of assigning values to the variables using `=`, you can make them into rules. For example, here is a collection of "variable names" and values for those variables, and a rule to make the assignment explicit:

```
vars = {a, b, c, d, e};
vals = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1.1};
Thread[Rule[vars, vals]]

{a -> 5, b -> 4, c -> 3, d -> 2, e -> 1.1}
```

To get the output you want is now easy:

```
vars[[Ordering[vals]]]

{e, d, c, b, a}
```

(Thanks to Mike Honeychurch for the simplification!)

Comment: I was going to suggest this...glad I read the responses first for a change. (Always easier to upvote than to code.)

Comment: or just `Thread[Rule[vars, vals]]`

Answer (score 8):

As a followup to the answer by bill s, as of version 10, you should consider using `Association` instead of lists of rules. In this case, you could do the following:

```
Sort[AssociationThread[{a, b, c, d, e}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1.1}]]

(* <|e -> 1.1, d -> 2, c -> 3, b -> 4, a -> 5|> *)
```

and then

```
Keys@%

(* {e, d, c, b, a} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Hold` instead of `List` in `varList`:

```
a = 5; b = 4; c = 3; d = 2; e = 1;

varList = Hold[a, b, c, d, e];

SortBy[varList, # &]
(* Hold[e, d, c, b, a] *)
```