# Table of references

Tags: function-construction, syntax, variable-definitions

I have a list of variables (say `a, b, c, d, e`) that I want to assign in a single command.

```
{a,b,c,d,e} = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

would work, but it is cumbersome to type `{a,b,c,d,e}` each time. Is there a way I can create a table that holds references to these variables, and whenever I assign to this table, the actual variables `a,b,c,d,e` will get assigned?

Sorry for the question - I am new to *Mathematica* and do not even know the basic terms. If you guessed I have a C++ background, you are right.

Comment: Is something like that ok: `list := {a, b, c, d, e}; 
Unevaluated[list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] /. OwnValues[list]`?

Comment: related: [40094](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40094/5478)

Comment: less related: [70250](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70250/5478)

Comment: **Proposed duplicate: [(10322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)**.  Also related: [(6511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121) (and see links below that one)

Comment: The functional programmer might wonder, why would you want to do that ? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Most user friendly approach, with function:

```
mySet[l_] := {a, b, c, d, e} = l
```

---

I'm not sure what is the general goal, but here's one way with `UpValues`:

```
table /: Set[table, l_] := ({a, b, c, d, e} = l);

table = Range[6, 10]; 
{a, b, c, d, e}
```

> ```
> {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

```
table = Range[1, 5];
{a, b, c, d, e}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

---

Different approach:

```
list := {a, b, c, d, e};  
Unevaluated[list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] /. OwnValues[list]
```