# Assign to variables inside Array, rather than changing array entries

Tags: assignment

I am generating an Array with symbolic coefficients:

```
coefficients = Array[c, 3]
> {c[1], c[2], c[3]}
```

I would like to assign a value to each of these generated coefficients, such that in one go, `c[1] = 2`, `c[2] = 4`, `c[3] = 6`. Now the following statement:

```
 coefficients = {2,4,6};
```

does *not* do that: it merely changes the array's entries, but doesn't actually assign anything to `c[1] ... c[3]`.

I've been trying to play with `Hold` and `Unevaluated` functions to achieve this, but to no avail. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you find the answer there? [72857](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72857/5478)

Comment: Thank you, that indeed had the answer: `Unevaluated[coefficients = {1, 2, 3}] /. OwnValues[coefficients]`
Should I delete this question as it's a duplicate?

Comment: You don't have to. It will stay here as a road sign for future visitors. This is FAQ but it is not easy to find since *keywords* are not obvious. So the more duplicates the better in this case.

Comment: For generalized handling of list assignments please see [(10322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)