# Is it possible to assign a value where the target is itself a variable

Tags: assignment, variable

If I have a variable `x := "a"`.
Is there a way I can use it to assign a value to `a`, by just referring to `x`?
If I try `Evaluate[x]=4` I get error messages about `Tag Times in x Null is protected`.
I would like some way of having it execute `a = 4`.

Comment: `x = "a"; Evaluate@Symbol[x] = 1; a`

Comment: This is kind of hard in Mathematica. One way to do this would be `Hold[x]/.OwnValues[x]/.Hold[var_]:>(var = 4)` assuming that `a` is a symbol. If a is a string name, then: `ToExpression[x, StandardForm, Function[var, var=4, HoldFirst]]`.

Comment: Maybe `x /: Set[x, y_] := Set[a, y]`?

Comment: closely related: [Table of references](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72857/5478)

Comment: Okay I found something on the web that almost helps, but when I try an pass Hold a list rather than hard code things it barfs. If I swap the commented line for the hard coded Hold it does what I expect. cols is {ra,dec,z}
`Print[cols]
l := Length[cols]
Print[l]
ClearAll[ra, assign]
assign[symbols_, idx_, val_] :=
 symbols[[{idx}]] /. _[x_] :> (x = val)
symbols = Hold @@ cols;
(*symbols=Hold[ra,dec,z]*)
Print["Assign"]
assign [symbols, 1, 4];
ra`

Answer (score 1):

adding one more and summarizing comments

```
     ToExpression[x <> "=" <> ToString[10]];
```

or

```
     ToExpression[StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {x, "=", 3.14}]
```

from: @LeonidShifrin

```
     ToExpression[x, StandardForm, Function[var, var = 42, HoldFirst]]
```

@belisarius approach only works once:

```
     Evaluate@Symbol[x] = 1
```

after "a" has a value, `Symbol[x]` returns the value so this breaks if you try to use it more than once.

@kuba proposes using TagSetDelayed x:

```
     x := "a" 
     x /: Set[x, y_] := Set[a, y]
```

which will let you simply do:

```
     x=3
```

with the result being assignment of "a"  `{x,a} -> {"a",3}`

Comment: oh i see, i didn't understand..