# Names of Variables in an Array

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, symbols, variable

```
Foo={1,2,3};
Bar={4,5,6};
Blech={Foo,Bar};
```

Is there some way to retrieve the name variable name "Foo" from Blech[[1]]?

Comment: closely related: [70250](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70250/5478) and I think this should answer your question: [40663](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40663/5478)