# How to set a particular element of a list to a number?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, variable-definitions, hold

I have a list `{a,b,c,d}`, and I want to set the 1st element and the 3rd elements equal to 5 and 8, respectively, leaving 2nd and 4th as they are (`{b,d}` used later). How is this done?

Later, I want to set the 2nd element and the 4th element to other numbers, then 1st and 2nd, and so on... I spent a lot of time working on this (yup, embarrassed) but cant find a solution.

Comment: If `list = {a, b, c, d}`, then do `list[[{1, 3}]] = {5, 8}` etc.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't set a and c equal to 5 and 8, respectively. I want to assign 5 to a, and 8 to c (but in list form). How is that done?

Comment: So you want to set the value of those symbols `a/c`? Do you want this to work once they have values etc?

Comment: `list /. {a->5, c->8}`?

Comment: Hi Kuba, Yes, and a & c (elements of the list) are randomly chosen - they can, on next iteration be b & d, too...

Comment: related: [40663](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40663/5478), [70250](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70250/5478)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use indexed variable for this kind of manipulations. See related topics for a background of what is about to happen: [40663](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40663/5478), [70250](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70250/5478).

You can do:

```
set // Attributes = {HoldFirst};
set[varList_, pos_, values_] := (
  Hold[varList] /. OwnValues[varList]
)[[{1}, pos]] /. Hold[vars_] :> Hold[vars = values] // ReleaseHold
```

Which is far from being neat but it works.

```
{a, b, c, d, e} = Range[5];
varList := {a, b, c, d, e};


varList

set[varList, {1, 3}, {15, 15}];
varList

set[varList, 2 ;;, {1, 11, 111, 111}];
varList
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>
> {15, 2, 15, 4, 5}
>
> {15, 1, 11, 111, 111}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As Kuba mentioned, it is better to use an indexed variable, so here are a couple of examples.

```
Clear[i]

list = i /@ Range[4]
```

> ```
> {i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4]}
> ```

```
(i[#1] = #2) & @@@ {{1, 5}, {3, 8}};

i /@ Range[4]
```

> ```
> {5, i[2], 8, i[4]}
> ```

```
Clear[x]

With[{x = i /@ {2, 4}}, x = {7, 9}];

list
```

> ```
> {5, 7, 8, 9}
> ```

```
Array[i, 4]
```

> ```
> {5, 7, 8, 9}
> ```