# List of (sub-)lists - query sub-lists by names?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the following very simple example:

```
list1 = {a11, a12, a13, a14, a15};
list2 = {a21, a22, a23, a24, a25};
list3 = {a31, a32, a33, a34, a35};
biglist = {list1, list2, list3};
```

are the names "list1", "list2", "list3" of the sub-lists "lost" inside the "biglist"? For example, if I need to know only which sub-lists are included in the "biglist" (by name), is this possible? Further, can I get, for example, the second element of all sub-lists, can I use something like
`newlista = biglist[[list3, [[2]]]]` instead of `newlist = biglist[[3,2]]` ?
This would be useful, for example, in case I don't know the order of the sub-lists inside the "biglist".

Comment: What version do you use? `Associations` are the way to go if 10+.

Comment: I have version 11, so it should be available. Thanks, I'll test it right now! It's difficult for me to search for functions which were new added to Mathematica: there are hundreds of them :-).

Comment: No problem. p.s. about your question, does the accepted answer in [".. list of assigned variables"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55764/5478) answer your doubts?

Comment: Yes, in a way...

Comment: I don't seem to be able to associate a list to a variable... in the linked questions / answers it is allways about associating values to varaibles.

Comment: oh, then I was thinking about something like `biglist = <|"list1" -> list1,...|>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elucidating Kuba's comments, here's how you can use [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) to accomplish your goals.

```
list1 = {a11, a12, a13, a14, a15};
list2 = {a21, a22, a23, a24, a25};
list3 = {a31, a32, a33, a34, a35};

lists = <|"list1" -> list1, "list2" -> list2, "list3" -> list3|>;
```

(After `lists` is defined `list1` etc. may be cleared.)

#### I need to know only which sub-lists are included in the "biglist" (by name)

```
Keys[lists]
```

> ```
> {"list1", "list2", "list3"}
> ```

#### can I get, for example, the second element of all sub-lists

```
lists[[All, 2]] // Values
```

> ```
> {a12, a22, a32}
> ```

#### can I use something like `newlista = biglist[[list3, [[2]]]]` ?

```
lists[["list3", 4]]
```

> ```
> a34
> ```

#### for example, in case I don't know the order of the sub-lists inside the "biglist"

```
(* pick one *)

{"list2", "list1"} /. lists

lists /@ {"list2", "list1"}

Lookup[lists, {"list2", "list1"}]
```

> ```
> {{a21, a22, a23, a24, a25}, {a11, a12, a13, a14, a15}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very precise and detailed answer!

Comment: Works perfect, it's a very logical way to do it and it's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple functions which - I think - could help:

```
l1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
l2 = {"e", "f", "g"};
l3 = {"h", "i", "j", "k", "l"};
l = {l1, l2, l3};

In[40]:= l[[3, 2]]

Out[40]= "i"

In[50]:= picker[a_?ListQ, x_?ListQ, y_?NumberQ] := 
 If[SubsetQ[Flatten[a], x], x[[y]]]

In[52]:= picker[l, l3, 2]

Out[52]= i
```

Comment: Also a useful approach, thanks.