# How to use an expression for the argument to a function

Tags: function-construction, core-language

I would like to define a function over a list of variables like

```
f[a_,b_,c_]:=a+b+c
```

However, when this list is big it makes uncomfortable to read. Can I somehow define a function in this way:

```
list={a_,b_,c_};
f[list]:=a+b+c
```

It will be perfect if the answer code will not request me to know the size of this list. I mean so that bigger list

```
list={a_,b_,c_,d_} Improved formatting
```

will not cause me to change the previous definition

```
f[list]:=a+b+c
```

For example here I'm trying to define all neccessary functions. Some use already defined functions. But you can see that I have to rewrite all needed variables every time I define new function. It's really annoying to spend the time seeking what variables I could miss, because they all need diferent variables.

```
(*All functions' definitions:*)
(*Fixed costs*)
F=1.;
(*Variable part of cost function with ponetial nonlinearity*)
c[f_]:=1/f;
(*Dirty quantity*)
Q[L1_,L2_,x1_,x2_,τ_]:=L1*x1+L2*x2*τ;
(*Pure quantity*)
Q$pure[L1_,L2_,x1_,x2_,τ_]:=L1*x1+L2*x2;
(*Cost function*)
V[L1_,L2_,x1_,x2_,τ_,f_]:=c[f]*Q[L1,L2,x1,x2,τ]+F;
(*Derivative of cost function with respect to Q dirty, made by inverse chain rule*)
Der$V[L1_,L2_,x1_,x2_,τ_,f_]:=Derivative[0,0,1,0,0,0][V][L1,L2,x1,x2,τ,f]/Derivative[0,0,1,0,0][Q][L1,L2,x1,x2,τ];
(*wage*)
w[x$HH_,x$HF_,x$FH_,x$FF_,L$H_,L$F_,τ_,f_,a_,m_]:=x$FH/x$HF*(1-ru[x$HF,a,m])/(1-ru[x$FH,a,m])*V[L$H,L$F,x$HH,x$HF,τ,f]/Der$V[L$H,L$F,x$HH,x$HF,τ,f]*Der$V[L$F,L$H,x$FF,x$FH,τ,f]/V[L$F,L$H,x$FF,x$FH,τ,f];
(*Lagrangian multiplier fo Home*)
λ$H[x$HH_,x$HF_,x$FH_,x$FF_,L$H_,L$F_,τ_,f_,a_,m_]:=Derivative[1,0,0][u][x$HH,a,m]*(1-ru[x$HH,a,m])/w[x$HH,x$HF,x$FH,x$FF,L$H,L$F,τ,f,a,m]/Der$V[L$H,L$F,x$HH,x$HF,τ,f];
(*Lagrangian multiplier fo Foreign*)
λ$F[x$HH_,x$HF_,x$FH_,x$FF_,L$H_,L$F_,τ_,f_,a_,m_]:=Derivative[1,0,0][u][x$FF,a,m]*(1-ru[x$FF,a,m])/Der$V[L$F,L$H,x$FF,x$FH,τ,f];
(*Total number of firms in a contry*)
N$[L1_,L2_,x1_,x2_,τ_,f_]:=L1/V[L1,L2,x1,x2,τ,f];
```

One way I'm trying to solve this problem is this:

```
vl = {a_, m_, s_, τ_, c_, x$HH_, x$HF_, x$FF_, x$FH_, λ$H_, λ$F_, L$H_, L$F_, w_, δ_};
vle = {a, m, s, τ, c, x$HH, x$HF, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, δ};
vle1 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, 1};
xx[vl] := vle
xx[vle1]
```

But it doesn't work because I can't make *Mathematica* think about "vl" in the definition of function "xx" as taken representation of "vl", but without blanks. If I ask

```
xx[vle1]
```

it returns

```
{a, m, s, τ, c, x$HH, x$HF, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, δ}
```

Comment: Look up *Apply*,  *__*,  *_List* in the Documentation. With knowledge about these three you should be abe to answer your own question.

Comment: It can be done, but it doesn't look like a good idea.    `With[{list = {a_, b_, c_}}, f[list] := a + b + c]`.  Try not to do this.  Also, this won't work in every situation.   I really can't understand why you can't just inline `list`.  Why don't you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?  There's very likely a much better solution.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Inline means just write it in a row `f[a_,b_,c_]`?
The reason is that I ahve a lot of function definition. And some functions need already defined functios. Like:
`p$HH[x$HH_] := Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x$HH, a, m]/\[Lambda]$H`

`p$HF[x$HF_] := Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x$HF, a, m]/\[Lambda]$F`

`\[Nu]$H[L$H_, L$F_, x$HH_, x$HF_, \[Tau]_, 
  f_] := (L$H*p$HH[x$HH]*x$HH + L$F*p$HF[x$HF]*x$HF - 
   w*(c*(L$H*x$HH + \[Tau]*L$F*x$HF) + F))`

And if I forgot to include any small variable it doesn't work and it is not convinient....

Comment: wouldn't `f[list_]:=Total@list` solve it? (ahem, this is what @sektor meant with `Apply`)

Comment: The summation here is just to simplify things. Ofcourse I will use some complex operations.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. But maybe you could post these functions as working examples in the original post?

Comment: Included the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach seems to work.

```
Clear@f
list = {a, b, c}
argList := Evaluate@
   Sequence @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ list)

f[argList] := a + b + c

DownValues@f
 (* {HoldPattern[f[a_, b_, c_]] :> a + b + c} *)

f[1, 2, 3]
 (* 6 *)
```

I think it fits your request.  If not, maybe try manipulating `DownValues[f]` directly, but it won't be elegant!

## Edit: Code hygiene issues — scope

This code is a bit unhygienic because it uses global definitions for function arguments (i.e. things that should be local).  There is a significant risk of confusing side effects.

`list` has to be correctly defined at the time `f[arglist]` is called.  After that, you can over-write it.  This is problematic because `list` isn't apparent in the line `f[argList] := a + b + c`; so another reader wouldn't necessarily realise that overwriting `list` would cause that definition to fail.  Much the same is true of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: I see your point... But can I make it simplier? I added the way I'm trying now to my question. But I can't make it work. However you way is also very nice!

The added question starts from "One way I'm trying to solve this problem is this:"

Comment: Sorry, you way is actually the BEST!

Answer (score 1):

### Simplest solution

Use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html):

```
vl = {a_, m_, s_, τ_, c_, x$HH_, x$HF_, x$FF_, x$FH_, λ$H_, λ$F_, L$H_, L$F_, w_, δ_};
vle = {a, m, s, τ, c, x$HH, x$HF, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, δ};
vle1 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, 1};
xx[vl] = vle;
xx[vle1]
xx[2 vle1]
(*  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, 1}  *)
(*  {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 x$FF, 2 x$FH, 2 λ$H, 2 λ$F, 2 L$H, 2 L$F, 2 w, 2} *)
```

This has pitfalls and does not quite address all the conditions set out in the OP's question.  First, if the variables in `vle = {a,...}` have values, then they will be used instead of the symbols when `xx` is defined. If for instance `a = 43` at the time `xx[vl] = vle` is executed, then `xx[vle1]` would return `{43, 1,...}`.  Assuming `vl` is a flat list of named patterns, a workaround is to block all the symbols used as pattern names using an [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19758/how-to-set-block-local-variables-by-code/19761#19761):

```
Hold @@ vl /. Verbatim[Pattern][v_, _] :> v /. Hold[vars___] :>
 Block[{vars}, xx[vl] = vle]
```

Second, this solution doesn't satisfy the desired property that the definition depends on `vl`.  The symbol `vl` is evaluated and replaced by an explicit list of argument patterns before the down-value for `xx` is created.

```
??xx
(*
  xx[{a_,m_,s_,τ_,c_,x$HH_,x$HF_,x$FF_,x$FH_,λ$H_,λ$F_,L$H_,L$F_,w_,δ_}] =
   {a,m,s,τ,c,x$HH,x$HF,x$FF,x$FH,λ$H,λ$F,L$H,L$F,w,δ}
*)
```

The solution `f[argList] := a + b + c` by [djp](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/25325/djp) also has this drawback.  In both solutions, `xx` has to be redefined if `vl` is changed.

### Solution to an implicit question

> It's really annoying to spend the time seeking what variables I could miss...

Here is a function that will check the definitions (i.e. each down value) of a function and report `` Global` `` symbols present in the definition but missing from the arguments.  (There seemed to me to be both advantages and disadvantages to making `getHeldSymbols` and `getHeldPatternNames` both `HoldAll` and adapting the code of `missingArgs` to those attributes.  I could not decide which way was best.)

```
ClearAll[getHeldSymbols, getHeldPatternNames];
getHeldSymbols[e_] := DeleteDuplicates@
  Cases[e, v_Symbol /; Context[v] === "Global`" :> Hold[v], Infinity];
getHeldPatternNames[e_] := DeleteDuplicates@
  Cases[e, Verbatim[Pattern][v_, _] :> Hold[v], Infinity]

ClearAll[missingArgs];
missingArgs::nofn = "Symbol `` has no down values.";
missingArgs[f_Symbol] /; DownValues[f] =!= {} :=
  missingArgs /@ DownValues[f];
missingArgs[Verbatim[HoldPattern][f_[args___]] :> val_] :=
  HoldPattern[f[args]] -> Complement[
    getHeldSymbols[Hold[val]],
    getHeldPatternNames[Hold[args]]
    ];
missingArgs[f_Symbol] := Message[missingArgs::nofn, f];
```

Examples:

```
Clear[f];
f[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c;
missingArgs[f]
  (*
   {HoldPattern[f[a_, b_, c_]] -> {}}
  *)
Clear[f];
f[a_, b_, c_] := a + Exp[c] + d;
missingArgs[f]
  (*
   {HoldPattern[f[a_, b_, c_]] -> {Hold[d]}}
  *)
Clear[f];
f[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c + d;
f[{a_, b_, c_}] := a + Exp[c] + e;
missingArgs[f]
  (*
   {HoldPattern[f[a_, b_, c_]] -> {Hold[d]}, 
    HoldPattern[f[{a_, b_, c_}]] -> {Hold[e]}}
  *)
```

### Improvement or triviality? Re my original interpretation and solution

The problem originally appeared to me to be one of constructing a function definition that would at run-time adapt to a dynamically changing argument pattern.  In its general scope, such a problem is **not a duplicate** of [Can a function be made to accept a variable amount of inputs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/can-a-function-be-made-to-accept-a-variable-amount-of-inputs).  The MWE, which might not reflect the subtleties of the general use-case, might be solved with code like one of the following or approaches from the linked question:

```
f[{a_, b_, c_, ___}] := a + b + c;
f[list_] /; Length[list] >= 3 := Total[list[[ ;; 3]]];
```

On the other hand, most situations do not require such indirect function construction as shown below, and I have to echo [Szabolcs's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) comment that there is probably a better approach.

Indeed, here's a general solution for creating a delayed function evaluation that adapts to changes to the argument pattern, but which raises the question of the triviality of the problem.  It stores the argument patterns and replacement value in `delayedFunction`, which is evaluated when passed an input.

```
ClearAll[setDelayedDelayed, delayedFunction];
SetAttributes[setDelayedDelayed, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[delayedFunction, HoldAll]; 
setDelayedDelayed[f_Symbol, args_, val_] /; ListQ[args] := 
  f = delayedFunction[args, val];
With[{f = Unique[]}, 
  delayedFunction[args_, val_][x___] /; MatchQ[{x}, args] := 
   Thread[getHeldPatternNames[Evaluate@args], Hold] /. 
    Hold[vars_] :> Block[vars, Block @@ Hold[{f}, (f[##] = val) & @@ args; f[x]]]
  ];
```

Example:

```
Clear[xx, a];
vl = {a_, m_, s_, τ_, c_, x$HH_, x$HF_, x$FF_, x$FH_, λ$H_, λ$F_, L$H_, L$F_, w_, δ_};
vle = {a, m, s, τ, c, x$HH, x$HF, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, δ};
a = 43;   (* to verify that  a  is blocked *)

setDelayedDelayed[xx, {vl}, vle]
(*  delayedFunction[{vl}, vle]  *)

xx[vle1]
(*  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, 1}  *)

AppendTo[vl, dummy_]     (* add an extra argument to  vl  *)
(*  {a_, m_, s_, τ_, c_, x$HH_, x$HF_, x$FF_, x$FH_, λ$H_, λ$F_, L$H_, L$F_, w_, δ_,
     dummy_}  *)

xx[Append[vle1, extra]]  (* and an extra input *)
(*  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, x$FF, x$FH, λ$H, λ$F, L$H, L$F, w, 1}  *)
```

What the code shows, *Mathematica* already has such functions for constructing functions at run-time, namely `Set` and `SetDelayed` (even `ReplaceAll` could be used).  The only nontrivial aspect is localizing the arguments in `args` and `val`.  But that can be done as shown at the end of the simplest answer.  One of the sillier things about the `delayedFunction` solution is that the function is basically constructed each time it is evaluated.  This is probably fast in almost all cases, so it is not terribly inefficient.

### Original solution

In any case, working from my initial interpretation, it seems to me that if the list of arguments changes, the expression the function computes might change, too.  There are two forms for the argument pattern, one which appears in the OP's question and one that appears in [djp's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/25325/djp) answer.  It is easy to give both.

```
arglist = {a_, b_, c_};
expr = a + b + c;

Clear[f];
f[x_] /; MatchQ[x, arglist] := 
 x /. arglist -> (Hold[expr] /. OwnValues[expr]) // ReleaseHold

f[{x, y, z}]
(*  x + y + z  *)
```

---

```
Clear[f];
f[x__] /; MatchQ[{x}, arglist] :=
   {x} /. arglist -> (Hold[expr] /. OwnValues[expr]) // ReleaseHold

f[x, y, z]
(*  x + y + z  *)

arglist = {a_, b_, c_, d_};
expr = a + b + c + 2 d;
f[x, y, z, w]
(*  2 w + x + y + z  *)
```

If any of the variables have a value, then the values will be substituted in the assignment to `expr`, which is probably an undesired behavior.  A way around this is to `Block` the variables while `expr` is being defined.

```
Block @@ (Hold[#,
      expr = a + b + c + d
      ] &@arglist /. Verbatim[Pattern][x_, _] :> x)
```